# Export email activity as CSV in Sendgrid

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

Can anyone please help me on this. I would like to track the user activity in Excel, about their open, click status. I could see them in UI portal. Is there any option to export as CSV?

Thanks in advance.
Bose

Comment: I got the reference here to do API implementation. But it will be great help if I could do this in Sendgrid UI.https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Track/Collecting_Data/can_i_download_a_list_of_click_and_or_open_events.html

Comment: The answer is right in the link you posted. It very clearly says there is no way to do this from the UI.

Comment: Yeah Sendgrid, why no CSV export here? thats just plain lazy

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Keen IO SendGrid integration](https://keen.io/docs/integrations/sendgrid/). It collects and stores your SendGrid event data automatically and stores it forever.  You to do downloads in the UI or programmatically, and provides a bunch of other functionality that may also be useful.

You can also use it to export some or all of your data to CSV and custom audiences based on arbitrary segmentation, like user behavior or custom attributes (what SendGrid calls `Unique Arguments.`